# How to INSERT repeated values like (a,b,c,d,a,b,c,d....) in DB table?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, schedule

I try to make work schedule table.

I have a table like:

| shift_starts_dt | shift_type |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 08:00:00 | Day |
| 2022-01-01 20:00:00 | Night |
| 2022-01-02 08:00:00 | Day |
| 2022-01-02 20:00:00 | Night |
| 2022-01-03 08:00:00 | Day |
| 2022-01-03 20:00:00 | Night |
| 2022-01-04 08:00:00 | Day |
| 2022-01-04 20:00:00 | Night |

*etc.. until the end of the year*

I can't figure out how to add repeated values to table.

I want to add the 'shift_name' column that contains 'A','B','C','D' (It's like name for team)

What query should I use to achieve the next result:

| shift_starts_dt | shift_type | shift_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 08:00:00 | Day | 'A' |
| 2022-01-01 20:00:00 | Night | 'B' |
| 2022-01-02 08:00:00 | Day | 'C' |
| 2022-01-02 20:00:00 | Night | 'D' |
| 2022-01-03 08:00:00 | Day | 'A' |
| 2022-01-03 20:00:00 | Night | 'B' |
| 2022-01-04 08:00:00 | Day | 'C' |
| 2022-01-04 20:00:00 | Night | 'D' |

. . .  . . .

Comment: What do you mean "until the end of the year"? All dates in your data are the same date `2022-01-01`. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, the question have been edited. I mean the table is like a calendar from 2022-01-01 to 2022-12-31. Every day divided on two parts - work shift from 8:00, and next one from 20:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use number of half days since Jan 1 modulus 4 to index an array:

```sql
select
  shift_starts_dt,
  shift_type,
  (array['A','B','C','D'])[(extract(epoch from shift_starts_dt - '2022-01-01')::int / 43200) % 4 + 1]
from work_schedule
```

See [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1890c/1).

You could replace `'2022-01-01'` with `(select min(shift_starts_dt) from work_schedule)` for a more general solution.